# Buñuel's movies in languages other than Spanish or French

Tags: luis-bunuel

I read somewhere that [Buñuel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luis_Bu%C3%B1uel) made movies in three languages.  All I know are his movies in Spanish and French.  Is that true and in which other languages has he directed movies and what are those movies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to IMDB, he directed two movies in English:

- [Robinson Crusoe (1954)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0044386/)
- [The Young One (1960)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053967/)

[Filmography in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luis_Bu%C3%B1uel_filmography) includes movies in French, Spanish and English.